# Adding Attributes to Select Options in Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm trying to add extra HTML attributes to some select options in a dropdown list in Joomla 2.5, and want to use the built-in HTML helpers rather than write the HTML by myself. The current output is:

```
<select>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>
```

but I would like it to be something like:

```
<select>
    <option value="Red" data-img="red.jpg">Red</option>
</select>
```

so that I can access the data-img attribute using Javascript when the selected option changes.

I'm creating the select options like so:

```
$select = JHtml::_('select.option', "Red", "Red");
```

and then passing them to JHTML to create the generic list HTML:

```
$html = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', ...);
```

I've looked through the documentation and tried passing various different parameter to the functions, but it's very confusing in terms of all the options (`option.attr`, `attr` etc) that the functions use, and Google has turned up nothing either.

Can anyone tell me what extra parameters I need to pass to the functions to get it properly add the extra attributes to the `<option>` elements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To say "a dropdown list in Joomla 2.5" is vague would be an understatement.  There are hundreds of them in Joomla, so something more specific might spark an answer from someone.

Comment: The question was about the HTML helper functions that are used to build select lists, not a specific one that is part of Joomla, so I can't really be more specific.

Comment: Fair enough.  The question included "...some select options in a dropdown...", so that implied that you had something particular in mind with no examples to explain what it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling on this exact scenario today, needing to add some extra data with the select's options. After a thorough analyze of the joomla/libraries/joomla/html/html/select.php file, I succeeded to do this with a few downside...

First, in my case, the data used for the select is coming from the database, and need some preparation for this scenario :

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = 'SELECT  nom AS value , nom AS text, prix FROM #__reservation_nourritures order by `ordering` asc';
$db->setQuery($sql);
$nourritures = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($nourritures as $nourriture){
    //the data to use MUST be in an array form for the extra html attributes...
    $nourriture->data = array('data'=>$nourriture->prix);
}
```

Once the data is ready, you can pass it to the JHTML function to build the select :

```
echo JHTML::_('select.genericlist',$nourriture,'myId',array('class'=>'nourritures','option.attr'=>'data'));
```

In short, the 'option.attr' must be used to insert attributes into the options. Note : The select.genericlist function **MUST** have only 3 arguments for this to work. From what I understand from the function, attributes only get merged into the options if you pass exactly 3 arguments to the function, otherwise it just ignores it. So if you want, as exemple, to define a preselected option with the additional parameters, you are out of luck. Here is the part regarding this in the function :

```
if (is_array($attribs) && func_num_args() == 3)
{
    // Assume we have an options array
    $options = array_merge($options, $attribs);
}
```

To my understanding, this is a bug and/or a bad behavior. I'll fill in a bugg in the joomla tracker when I get time.

Comment: Yep - that code works perfectly until you add more than 3 arguments to the function call, then the extra options aren't output. This will explain why I couldn't get it working - my function call requires more than 3 arguments. Good find! Surprised this hasn't cropped up before, I hope it can get fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$option = JHtml::_('select.option', "Red", "Red", array('option.attr' => 'optionattr', 'attr' => array('data-img' => "red.jpg")));
```

or like this

```
$option = JHtml::_('select.option', "Red", "Red");

$option->optionattr = array(
    'data-img' => "red.jpg"
);
```